# Access SQL Summarize Data

Tags: sql, ms-access, summary, jet, summarization

I can get the output that I want from the data my query provides in Excel, but it would be nice to be able to do it in Access directly.

I return a table like this:

```
Date          kName   NumKits   ActKits  dName  NumDoses   ActDoses
---------------------------------------------------------------------
11/03/2018    AA      5         1000     BB     12         3400
12/03/2018    CC      7         1100     AA     10         4120
etc..
```

Any name could appear in either column, maybe both columns at the same time. The criteria for the data as provided is a date range.

I want this information summarized, as follows:

```
     (Sum)     (Sum)        (Count)     (Sum)      (Sum)         (Count)
Name KitMade   KitActivity  KitSession  DosesMade  DoseActivity  DoseSession
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
AA   26         42015       3           40         35420         4
BB (etc...)
```

retaining the date filter.

My initial thought is to do the query twice, separating out Kits and Doses then combining them back together; but I'm sure that there must be a simpler way?

Using Access 2016, data has all been changed from actual information.

Comment: What do your results have to do with the sample data?  Where do "42015" and "35420" come from?

Comment: Edited for more clarity, the summarised numbers are the sum of previous values (SUM(NumKits)=KitMade, SUM(ActKits)=KitActivity, COUNT(kName)=KitSession (All where Name=kName), same for doses but with dName).

Comment: The names / numbers themselves were made up for the purposes of the question.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there.  If the example figures don't add up to the example results I generally spend a few seconds (sometimes minutes) wondering why it doesn't add up and trying to figure out what heading goes with what and then move on to the next question rather than figure out what hasn't been said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select name, sum(numkits) as numkits, sum(actkits) as actkits, sum(kitcnt) as numkits,
       sum(numdoses) as numdoses, sum(actdoses) as actdoses, sum(dosecnt) as dosecnt
from (select kname as name, 1 as kitcnt, numkits, actkits, 0 as dosecnt, 0 as numdoses, 0 as actdoses
      from t
      union all
      select kname, 0 as kitcnt, 0 as numkits, 0 as actkits, 1 as dosecnt, numdoses, actdoses
      from t
     ) as t
group by name;
```

I think some older versions of MS Access do not support `union all` in the `FROM` clause.  If that is a problem, you can get around it by creating a view.

Comment: I had to wrap my UNION ALL with a SELECT of its own, then do SUM and GROUP BY on that, but this is working, hank you very much.

Comment: Removed my extra select - removed the brackets around the Union tables

Comment: @Sam . . . Oh, I thought SQLite was the only database that didn't allow parentheses.